# Indentation of new list levels with enumitem

Tags: lists, indentation, itemize, enumitem

I am using `enumitem` package in order to extend latex default 4 itemize-list levels. So far, everything works, but I realized, that a proper  indentation of new list levels is missing. Here an example:

```
\documentclass{scrartcl}

\usepackage{textcomp}
\usepackage{mathabx}

\usepackage{enumitem}
\setlistdepth{8}
\setlist[itemize,1]{label=\textbullet}
\setlist[itemize,2]{label=\textopenbullet}
\setlist[itemize,3]{label=$\blacktriangleright$}
\setlist[itemize,4]{label=$\smalltriangleright$}
\setlist[itemize,5]{label=$\sqbullet$}
\setlist[itemize,6]{label=$\square$=}
\setlist[itemize,7]{label=$\blackdiamond$}
\setlist[itemize,8]{label=$\diamond$}
\renewlist{itemize}{itemize}{8}

\begin{document}

\begin{itemize}
\item Level 1
  \begin{itemize}
  \item Level 2
    \begin{itemize}
    \item Level 3 
      \begin{itemize}
      \item Level 4
        \begin{itemize}
        \item Level 5
          \begin{itemize}
          \item Level 6
            \begin{itemize}
            \item Level 7
              \begin{itemize}
              \item Level 8
              \end{itemize}
            \end{itemize}
          \end{itemize}
        \end{itemize}
      \end{itemize}
    \end{itemize}
  \end{itemize}
\end{itemize}

\end{document}
```

This code provides following output:

[image]

As one can see, the item "bullets" on the first 4 levels are each indented in relation to the upper level text. But for the last 4 which are defined by my own, "bullets" are horizontally on the same line as upper layer text.

Now, I cannot figure out, how to adjust the list so that every list level has the same indentation.

Comment: I would guess the default indentation scheme for items of level 4 thru 8 was chosen so as to preserve a minimal amount of usable space for actual text. Conversely, the more space is set aside for indentation, the less space there is for real text.

Comment: Your indentation is better, in my opinion.

Answer (score 3):

What about this?

```
\documentclass{scrartcl}

\usepackage{textcomp}
\usepackage{mathabx}

\usepackage{enumitem}
\setlistdepth{8}
\setlist{leftmargin = *}
\setlist[itemize,1]{label=\textbullet}
\setlist[itemize,2]{label=\textopenbullet}
\setlist[itemize,3]{label=$\blacktriangleright$}
\setlist[itemize,4]{label=$\smalltriangleright$}
\setlist[itemize,5]{label=$\sqbullet$,leftmargin = 1cm}
\setlist[itemize,6]{label=$\square$=,leftmargin = 1cm}
\setlist[itemize,7]{label=$\blackdiamond$,leftmargin = 1cm}
\setlist[itemize,8]{label=$\diamond$,leftmargin = 1cm}
\renewlist{itemize}{itemize}{8}

\begin{document}

\begin{itemize}
\item Level 1
  \begin{itemize}
  \item Level 2
    \begin{itemize}
    \item Level 3
      \begin{itemize}
      \item Level 4
        \begin{itemize}
        \item Level 5 Lalala Lalala Lalala Lalala Lalala Lalala Lalala Lalala Lalala Lalala Lalala Lalala 
            \begin{itemize}
            \item Level 6
            \begin{itemize}
            \item Level 7
              \begin{itemize}
              \item Level 8
              \end{itemize}
            \end{itemize}
          \end{itemize}
        \end{itemize}
      \end{itemize}
    \end{itemize}
  \end{itemize}
\end{itemize}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Looks nice, thanks! But is there also a possibility to increase identation for levels 5-8? IMHO, larger identation makes the list better readable (otherwise I wouldn't ever recognise the issue, I think :) )

Comment: Yes/ You can overwrite the value of `leftmargin` from level 5 on. Please see my updated code if it's something like that you want.